# rgba gradient with opacity

Tags: webkit, gradient, opacity, rgba

I have this code for a transparent rgba gradient but one works and the other doesn't and I can't figure out why

**Working one**

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left , rgba(189,206,226,0.6) 0%, rgba(191,217,242,0.6) 32%, rgba(14,94,95,0.6) 65%);
```

**Non working one**

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left , rgba(189,206,226,0.6) 0%, rgba(191,217,242,0.6) 32%, rgba(14,94,95,0.6) 60%), rgba(14,94,95,0.6) 5%);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe take out the `)` after `60%`

the Non-working one has `rgba(14,94,95,0.6) 60%)`
replace it with `rgba(14,94,95,0.6) 60%`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `)` after `60%)` in the 2nd rule

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left , rgba(189,206,226,0.6) 0%, rgba(191,217,242,0.6) 32%, rgba(14,94,95,0.6) 60%, rgba(14,94,95,0.6) 5%);
```